# Merge order with items in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, expand

I have a dataset with all the order, customer and orderitem information. I wandt to expand my orderitems in new columns, but without losing the information about the customer

```
CustomerId    OrderId    Item
1    1    CD
1    1    DVD
2    2    CD
```

And the result should be somehow:

```
CustomerId    OrderId    CD    DVD
1    1    1    1
2    2    1    0
```

I tried

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.Item)], axis='columns')
df2 = df2.groupby('CustomerId')
```

Comment: Like this: `pd.crosstab([df.CustomerId, df.OrderId], df.Item).reset_index()`

Comment: I am a bit curious - you need count duplicated values or need `0,1` in outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler is [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html);

```
pd.crosstab([df.CustomerId, df.OrderId], df.Item).reset_index()

   CustomerId  OrderId  CD  DVD
0           1        1   1    1
1           2        2   1    0
```

---

Or, [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) **if performance is important**.

```
df.pivot_table(index=['CustomerId', 'OrderId'], 
               columns=['Item'], 
               aggfunc='size', 
               fill_value=0)

Item                CD  DVD
CustomerId OrderId         
1          1         1    1
2          2         1    0
```

---

If you want to use dummies, [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) is another option:

```
# Solution similar to @jezrael but with str.get_dummies
(df.set_index(['CustomerId', 'OrderId'])
   .Item.str.get_dummies()
   .sum(level=[0, 1])
   .reset_index())

   CustomerId  OrderId  CD  DVD
0           1        1   1    1
1           2        2   1    0
```

If you need the indicator,

```
(df.set_index(['CustomerId', 'OrderId'])
   .Item.str.get_dummies()
   .max(level=[0, 1])
   .reset_index())
```

Comment: @jezrael Before taking the high road, keep in mind this was a duplicate. I reopened it and answered because you did not delete your answer.

Comment: yes, reason was I think OP need something else, but I was wrong, clear dupe...